# Why render time in blender is increasing 10 times after rotating 3d model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

I'm rendering  [this scene](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgwfBtrLYAWMhghgSwStHakbvuAY) in cycles (blender) on GPU with GTX 780 3GB
In preview mode it takes about 2mins to render 2000 samples.
[image: render time in preview mode]
In final render mode it takes about 40 seconds
[image: render time in final render]
But i need to rotate scene and render it from different view.
After rotation the model, render time has been increased to 20 times (to 20 mins per a frame)
[image: render time after rotate]
But in preview mode it still renders for 2 mins
[image: preview mode after rotatio]

what's the problem?
Problem appears only after rotating the object. If i moove the camera and NOT rotate the object it renders for 2 mins. But I need to rotate the object and not moove camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted at Blender's bug tracker and it seemed for first look as a bug, but 
Brecht Van Lommel (Rendering Software Engineer) explained:

> This is a typical issue with raytracers, many long thin faces along one direction are difficult to fit well in a BVH unless the faces are aligned to the X/Y/Z axis.
>   Also, the workaround is to subdivide the object more so the faces are not so long.

[image]

After subdivision mesh along faces render time decreased much.

[LINK](https://developer.blender.org/T56609) to this discussion on Blender's tracker.